# problem with starting values in optim function

Tags: r, optimization, log-likelihood

I'm working on an optimization problem using the optim function. The function to maximize is a likelihood function. I'm trying a very long list of data sets to be evaluated, and in some cases It gets messy because the lik.function does not converge because of the starting values. The example I provide is one in which the function does not find a solution. So, I would like to know a way to make the optimal function to select the starting values out of a grid of them, to find a solution otherwise to move on. This is my code, I try to make it the shortest I could. I'm sorry I'm using a lot of trycatch.

```
#data set
thisdata<-matrix(c(0.3014754, -1.8827312, 0.03221715, 0.08229814,
  1.7730673, -0.9852836, 0.12997904, 0.04904762,
  4.8520303, -1.2527630, 1.00781250, 0.12857143,
  1.9582560, -3.0834379, 0.04961323, 0.17430025,
  2.2284771, -2.5530445, 0.15824176, 0.08291110,
  3.3672958, -1.6218604, 0.25862069, 0.07484568,
  3.2358734, -1.3581235, 0.14847512, 0.06984127,
  0.5930637, -3.3499041, 0.03696742, 0.51754386,
  1.1451323, -3.0012725, 0.09415584, 0.11663597,
 1.7147984, -3.3843903, 0.04370370, 0.17231638), nrow = 10, ncol=4, byrow = T)
colnames(thisdata)<-c('eta.obs',     'xi.obs',    'var.eta',     'var.xi')

#likelihood function
lik.to.optim <- function(theta, data){


  mu.alpha <- theta[1]
  beta <- theta[2]
  mu.xi <- theta[3]
  sigma2.xi <- theta[4]
  sigma2.alpha<- theta[5]

  if(sigma2.xi <= 0 | sigma2.alpha <=0 | beta^2*sigma2.xi-sigma2.alpha<0)
  { 
    return(NA)
  }
  else{

    Sigma<-matrix(c(beta^2*sigma2.xi-sigma2.alpha,  beta*sigma2.xi-sigma2.alpha/beta, 
                    beta*sigma2.xi-sigma2.alpha/beta, sigma2.xi), 2,2)

    ris<-sum(dmvnorm(data[,1:2],c(mu.alpha+beta*mu.xi, mu.xi), Sigma, log=T))   
  }

  return(ris)
}

#another function calling the previous lik. function
fun_adicional<-function(base){
  NA.matrix<- matrix(NA, nrow=5, ncol=5)

  unos<-c(1,1,1,1,1)

  themle<-tryCatch(optim(unos, lik.to.optim, data=base, control=list(fnscale=-1))$par,
                   error=function(e) paste= c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), 
                   warning=function(w) paste=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))

  hessiano0 <- tryCatch(optim(unos, lik.to.optim, data=base, control= list(fnscale=-1),
                              hessian=T)$hessian,
                        error=function(e) paste= NA.matrix, 
                        warning=function(w) paste=NA.matrix)

  lavar<-tryCatch(solve(-hessiano0), error=function(e) paste= NA.matrix, 
                  warning=function(w) paste=NA.matrix)

  se_actual <- sqrt(diag(lavar))


  #double check
  if(any(is.na(se_actual))){

    #using the last mle estimate
    init <- themle
    ris.par <- tryCatch(optim(init, lik.to.optim, data=base, control=list(fnscale=-1))$par,
                        error=function(e) paste= c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), 
                        warning=function(w) paste=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))

    hessiano0 <- tryCatch(optim(ris.par, lik.to.optim, data=base, control= list(fnscale=-1), hessian=T)$hessian,
                          error=function(e) paste= NA.matrix, 
                          warning=function(w) paste=NA.matrix)

    naive_var_a<-tryCatch(solve(-hessiano0), error=function(e) paste= NA.matrix, 
                          warning=function(w) paste=NA.matrix)


    V_CV_list<-naive_var_a

    estimas<-ris.par
    st_err<-sqrt(diag(V_CV_list))

  } else{

    estimas<-mle.par
    V_CV_list<-lavar
    st_err<-se_actual

  }

  here<-list(themle,lavar)


  return(here)
}


fun_adicional(thisdata)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your question. It is not exactly clear to me. Do you have trouble finding an algorithm that creates good starting points (i.e.well distributed across parameter space)? Or did you hope that the optim function can handle that itself? In this case, I do not bleieve it can. You will have to write your own loop: 1. select starting point, 2. optimize, 3. Retry if solution is not acceptable.

Comment: Hey, I don't want to create an algorithm that creates good starting points. Let's say I invent the possible starting values that I would like to try, let's say a grid of them. I want the optim to try all the combinations of the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment I guess you want to run a grid search.  I'll use a simple example from `?optim`:

```
fr <- function(x) {   ## Rosenbrock Banana function
    x1 <- x[1]
    x2 <- x[2]
    100 * (x2 - x1 * x1)^2 + (1 - x1)^2
}
```

The solution for this function is a vector `x` of length 2.
So, run a `gridSearch`.

```
library("NMOF")
gridSearch(function(x, fr) optim(x, fn = fr)$value,
           fr = fr,
           levels = list(c(-1, -2),  ## the starting values
                         c(1, 2, 3)))

## 2 variables with 2, 3 levels: 6 function evaluations required.
## $minfun
## [1] 4.731118e-08
## 
## $minlevels
## [1] -1  1
```

So the best starting values are `c(-1, 1)`, which lead
to an objective function value of `4.731118e-08`.

The objective function values (`values`) for the other
starting points (`levels`) are also returned.

```
## $values
## [1] 4.731118e-08 1.605096e-06 4.568377e-07 1.006949e-06
## [5] 1.622874e-06 2.821143e-07
## 
## $levels
## $levels[[1]]
## [1] -1  1
## 
## $levels[[2]]
## [1] -2  1
## 
## $levels[[3]]
## [1] -1  2
## 
## $levels[[4]]
## [1] -2  2
## 
## $levels[[5]]
## [1] -1  3
## 
## $levels[[6]]
## [1] -2  3
```